# 8-bit AVR delay using TIMER0 (8-bit)

Tags: timer, assembly, arduino

Using an Atmega328P clocked externally @ 16 MHz, this procedure is analogous to delay routines that use instructions to consume clock cycles. The intent of this algorithm is not to advocate any particularly usefulness, but rather an alternative method of implementing delays in an application. The caveat would be a resolution of 10 ms and a range of 10 ms to 2.55 sec, with an accuracy of +/- 0.5%, but this is accomplished by using data that is only 8 bits wide.

The objective is to address the desired functionality based on a few simple criterion using the least amount of instructions.

```
        .def    TEMP        = R16
        .def    Iterations  = R17

        .equ       ZF = 1           ; Zero flag is bit 1 in SREG

; =============================================================================================
; Facilitates delays from 10 ms to 2.55 sec in 10 ms increments using TIMER0 on a Atmega328P
; running @ 16 mhz.

;   ENTER:  Iterations = Number of 10 ms intervals

;   LEAVE:  Iterations = 0 and TIMER0 is stopped.

;    NOTE: Actual delay/interation = 9.984 ms. (1 / (16e6 / 1024)) * 156
;                                                   F_CPU / Prescaler
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

Delay:  push    TEMP        

    ; Start TIMER0 on Arduino (Atmega328P)

        ; Table 14-9, page 110 of Datasheet 8161D-AVR-10/09

        ldi TEMP, (1 << CS02) | (1 << CS00)
        out TCCR0B, TEMP        ; Write to CS02:0

    ; Clear TCNT0 at beginning of each iteration. This also guarantees and residual value at
    ; first iteration will be overwitten.

        clr TEMP
        out TCNT0, TEMP     ; Reset counter

    ; Loop 156 times. 64 µs * 156 = 9.984 ms

Dly:    in  TEMP, TCNT0
        cpi TEMP, 156
        brlo    Dly         ; This works because TCNT0 is zero indexed.

        dec Iterations
        brne    Dly - 2         ; Back to top of outer loop if CY = 0

    ; Stop TIMER0

        out TCCR0B, Iterations
        pop TEMP
        ret
```

Code was tested with this short snippet on a Makerduino to strobe an LED for 20 ms every second for one minute. While code is running, onboard LED is on continuously and upon completion, both LEDs are off.

```
RESET:  ldi TEMP, high (RAMEND)
        out SPH, TEMP
        ldi TEMP, low (RAMEND)
        OUT SPL, TEMP

; ATmega328P pin 19 > Arduino pin 13 > PORTB pin 5 > ONBOARD LED.
;                18               12             4 > Red indicator LED

        ldi TEMP, (1 << PINB5) | (1 << PINB4)
        out DDRB, TEMP      ; Set pins as output
        sbi PINB, PINB5     ; Turn on onboard LED
        ldi TEMP, 60        ; Only for 60 times

Strobe: sbi PINB, PINB4
        ldi Iterations, 2
        rcall   Delay
        sbi PINB, PINB4
        ldi Iterations, 98
        rcall   Delay
        dec TEMP
        brne    Strobe

        sbi PINB, PINB5     ; Turn off onboard LED
```

Comment: May I ask what development tools you use for writing Atmega assembly?

Comment: @coderodde Atmel Studio 7.0.118 on Win7. To date, I'm using its simulator, but soon I think I'm going to have to invest in something like Atmel ICE.